# hyperlink text to mp3 without showing player

Tags: javascript, html, web

How do I create a text hyperlink to an mp3 file without showing the player.  For example, if I have the word "play" on my site and it is clicked, the associated mp3 will play without leaving the page and without a visible player.  Also, when right clicked, the person has an option to save/download the file.  The closest example I have found only allows you to copy the link location and not download/save the mp3 file.  Thanks.

```
    <!--[ In the head section of the HTML ]-->

<!--audio-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function play_single_sound() {
document.getElementById('audiotag').play();
}
</script>
<!--/audio-->

<!--[ In the body section of the HTML ]-->

<!--embedded audio-->
<div id="audio">
<audio id="audiotag" src="http://sample.mp3" autobuffer="autobuffer"></audio>
</div>
<!--/embedded audio-->

<!--button/link-->
<a href="javascript:play_single_sound();">play</a>
<!--/button/link-->

<!--[ Optional CSS ]-->
div#audio {
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Load the mp3 inside a iFrame width:0 and height:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `<a>` tag point to the mp3 file.  When you left-click, use JavaScript to play it.  When you right-click, you'll get the built-in menu with a "save link" option.

```
<a href="http://sample.mp3" id="audiolink">play</a>
```

Then in your JavaScript, you can prevent the default action of the link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('audiolink').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('audiotag').play();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to use something like [SoundManager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/).
It has a flash fallback for browsers that do not support html5 audio tag.

Demo of normal mp3 pimped up links: [play-mp3-links](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/play-mp3-links/basic.html)

Comment: Thanks for the lead.  I'll look into it.  The response I just marked as the answer worked well for me.

Comment: @user3080392 but remember that the accepted answer will not work in all browsers and also if you have multiple mp3 links. I recommend to look at soundmanager.

Comment: Yeah, you were right.  I tried to put a couple of links and it didn't work too well.  I'm going to also experiment with soundmanager.  Thanks